# DBeaver spatial output window: Is it possible to sync/filter spatial query to map bounds?

Tags: spatial-database, spatial-query, dbeaver

While upgrading PostGRES/PostGIS from 9.x to 11.x, I have discovered DBeaver and so far I am pleased.

Apparently it has some spatial integration, including the ability to visualize spatial data results using an integrated Leaflet map. Pretty cool. But I'm missing a slick way to support the query with a map bounds filter, or at least something loose like a right-click > "Copy Map Bounds" option on the map object itself, etc. After some experimentation and Googling I'm either not seeing it or I'm not using the right search terms.

Does anyone know if there is a built-in configuration to sync DBeaver's spatial results viewer's map bounds to the active query?

[image]

---

[**Edit: 5.8.2019**] Response to question in the comments. [DPSSpatial asked](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/322019/dbeaver-spatial-output-window-is-it-possible-to-sync-filter-spatial-query-to-ma#comment524066_322019)..

> ..do you mean that if you select * from a table, the results viewer will only show X amount of features, but if you zoom in, it will then show what is in the map view?

Note how, in this second graphic, the software imposes an arbitrary, customizable limit of 1000 records on any potential query--this is the circle in the lower-right. (I think it was originally 200 then I changed it.) That makes sense for either the Grid or Text view states, which are selectable just to the left of the output frame. But for the Spatial view state, to me, it makes more sense to sync the arbitrary limit to the integrated map's bounds, or to at least have that option, which is what led me to ask about this. However based on what I'm seeing in [the GitHub link](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/4222) DPSSpatial provided, I'm thinking this feature is so new it just hasn't evolved very far and likely this isn't possible. (Yet?) :)

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you're asking - do you mean that if you select * from a table, the results viewer will only show X amount of features, but if you zoom in, it will then show what is in the map view?

Comment: And keep in mind this feature is still in development: https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/4222

Comment: Looks like I'm going to have to upgrade da'beaver!